# How to pass a cell to a function in tableView swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I would like to pass a cell as a parameter to the function `datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker)`

The below is the part of the code, where I would like to achieve that, can someone please advice how I can achieve that ?

```
class DailyTimesTVC: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell

        cell.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }


    func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
        // Here I would like to access the cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend to use a callback closure

- In `DailyTimesTableViewCell` create a `callback` variable passing the `UIDatePicker` instance

  ```
  var callback : ((UIDatePicker) -> ())?
  ```
- In `DailyTimesTableViewCell` add the observer in `awakeFromNib`

  ```
  datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)
  ```
- In `DailyTimesTableViewCell` add the action method which calls the callback

  ```
  func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
     callback?(sender)
  }
  ```
- In `DailyTimesTVC` in `cellForRow` assign the callback closure

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell
      cell.callback = { datePicker in
          // do something with the date picker
      }
      return cell
  }
  ```

Is there any particular reason to use an extra nib for the cell? You can create multiple cells directly in the table view in Interface Builder.

Comment: As per your answer in second point where you asked to add observer, how can we use `viewDidLoad` in `DailyTimesTableViewCell` as this class is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and `UITableViewCell` doesn't have `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @vadian, Works perfectly Thanks!!